How can i change a column data type in pandas without creating null values in the whole column in my dataframe
I have been getting null values when trying to convert a column with the non-numeric  type values to a column with numeric type values
I have been using the below code line to change my column data type so that i can fill them null values in my 'gross' column but it has been giving me null values(Nan) in the whole 'gross' column what can i do:
# read['Gross']=pd.to_numeric(read['Gross'], errors='coerce')

It's difficult to answer your question without a [mre] of your data. Please provide the output of read['Gross'].head(50).tolist() (before converting to numeric).

The line pd.to_numeric(read['Gross'], errors='coerce') is correct for converting a column with potentially non-numeric values to numeric values in pandas. However, when errors='coerce' is used, any non-numeric value in the column will be replaced with NaN.
for Example:
data = {'Gross': ['1234', '$4567', '789a', '12,345', None]}
read = pd.DataFrame(data)
Clean and convert
read['Gross'] = read['Gross'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').replace('nan', '')
read['Gross'] = pd.to_numeric(read['Gross'], errors='coerce')
Handle NaN
read['Gross'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

It is likely that there are non-numeric values in the 'Gross' column. Inspect the columns for conformity of data type.
Check for Empty Strings or Fully Non-Numeric Rows
print(read[read['Gross'].isnull()])  

Remove leading/trailing spaces
read['Gross'] = read['Gross'].str.strip()
read['Gross'] = read['Gross'].str.replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True) 

Once cleaned, try the conversion again:
read['Gross'] = pd.to_numeric(read['Gross'], errors='coerce')

Fill missing values with 0
read['Gross'].fillna(0, inplace=True) 

